# How import existing eclipse project in to android studio 1.2.2?

Tags: android

I have project in eclipse and use android gingerbread, but when I need import this project to android studio 1.2. thin android show me massage to fixed my project after I click fixed show me error `"Execution failed for task  .

Comment: https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Open eclipce
```

Rigth click on project select Export

Select android 
    Select Generate Gradle build files
    click on next 
    select project and next
    and check Force overriding of existing file
    and click finise
Now your grdle file is redy to run in android studio

Now open android studio

Choose 'import project' in Android Studio
and select the following file path:
    F:\Eclipse Workspace\AndroidApp\build.gradle

Do NOT import the Eclipse project itself!

Answer (score 1):

**Export from Eclipse**

1.Update your Eclipse ADT Plugin (you must have version 22.0 or higher).

2.In Eclipse, select File > Export.

3.In the window that appears, open Android and select Generate Gradle build files.

4.Select the projects you want to export for Android Studio and click Finish.

Your selected projects remain in the same location but now contain a build.gradle file and are ready for Android Studio.

**Import into Android Studio**

1.In Android Studio, select File > Import Project.

2.Locate a project you exported from Eclipse, select the project's root directory and click OK.

3.Select Create project from existing sources and click Next.

4.Follow the walk-through to complete the import process.

for more info check out here : http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html#Export

Answer (score 0):

To migrate existing Android projects, simply import them using Android Studio:

In Android Studio, from the main menu or the Welcome to Android Studio page, 1)choose File > Import Project.

2)Select the Eclipse root project directory and click OK.

Note: The Eclipse root directory must contain the AndroidManifest.xml file. Also, the root directory must contain either the .project and .classpath files from Eclipse or the res/ and src/ directories.

3)Follow the steps in the import wizard.
source:- https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html